# Call Javascript function in .js file with React from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I haven't found this specific question so here it is:

Say I have an HTML file. In this HTML file I have some React-classes and functions in the body-element. One function is for rendering a form. Like this for example:

```
renderForm: function() {
      return (
      <div className="form_div">
        Movie search: <input type="text" className="query"></input>
        <button onClick={this.search} className="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    );
  },
```

Now. I also have a .js file. In this file I have a finished function "Search" to handle the user input and pass on to database/API/what I want to search through. It is a rather large function.

Can I call the Search function in this .js file with the React-code in my HTML-file?

The goal is to handle rendering with React, functionality with JS.

Is this possible (I'm not asking whether it's good practice or not)?

Comment: @nem035 How do one 'attach' it to the react component? I'm sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: posted an answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make sure to attach that function to your React component (so you can access it via `this`) or use the function directly (`search` instead of `this.search`) if you intend to keep it global (or perhaps imported from a [module](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.avxtrm3ws)).

I would say using it as an external function is easier:

```
renderForm: function() {
  return (
    <div className="form_div">
      Movie search: <input type="text" className="query"></input>
      <button onClick={search} className="submit">Search</button>
    </div>          /* ^------ search comes from a script that's loaded before this code so we can just call it */
  );
}
```

It will also be a better approach if the logic within `search` is more general or unrelated to the components you're creating because it will provide you with [looser coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

---

If the search depends on specific components (needs `this` binding), you'll need to attach it to your React components. The actual syntax depends if you're using [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) or [React.createClass](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html).

One approach using classes is to create a wrapper method around the global search that will call it with the proper context:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  search(...args) {
    search.apply(this, ...args); // <--- Call the global search but bind `this` to the React component instance.
  }

  // now you can use this.search in renderForm
  renderForm() { ... }
}
```

You could also attach `search` directly to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) of your component and not make the wrapper function:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...

  // you can use this.search in renderForm because it will be found on the prototype
  renderForm() { ... }
}

MyComponent.prototype.search = search; // <-- attach global search to the prototype of your component
```

As far as using `React.createClass`, you can just attach the reference to the global `search` to the object you pass in. Any functions that are called as methods on an object automatically have `this` set to that object:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  search: search, // <-- attach global search to your component,

  // now you can use this.search in renderForm because it is a method of your component
  renderForm() { ... }
});
```

Comment: This is a lovely, informative and useful reply. One that needs to be out there. Thank you!

Comment: @Zarkaylia glad to help out mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. That's very common and good practice to separate the functionality. Just make sure to **include** your js file in your html file.

Comment: Thank you for letting me now it's actually good practice. Somehow I have missed that/not been taught that.